# questions about shadow map PCF

Tags: directx-12

How to change the size of PCF kernel?
In book《Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 12》,it describes the 4-tap PCF Kernel, and it says we can decide the size of PCF Kenerl.But how to do this?

Comment: I successfully implemented Luna's PCF example in my own D3D12 project. Try modifying the 4-tap PCF kernel to a 9-tap kernel by creating an array of nine offset values, and then invoke the `SampleCmpLevelZero()` function in a loop that executes nine times.

Comment: But the meaning of invoking SampleCmpLevelZero() once doesn't change. It means doing comparison of depth for 4 times. Can i change this number"4" to nine?Or invoke this function in a loop has the same effect?

Comment: Yes it's true that one `SampleCmpLevelZero()` call will sample the shadow map four times using texture coordinate offsets it automatically calculates. I agree that the term '9-tap kernel' was confusing... by this I meant using a 3x3 box filter grid to execute `SampleCmpLevelZero()` nine times in a loop, which I believe is what Luna explains on p.660. The combination of a 3x3 box filter with a 4-tap kernel gives you 4x4 unique sample points. As to whether the samples able to be 'tapped' by `SampleCmpLevelZero()` itself can be increased, I'm not aware of any way of doing so or if it is possible.